# How to test zendesk function is called with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React component that when mounted creates a script element and either loads the ZenDesk script (which includes the statement $zopim.livechat.window.hide() or if it is already loaded, calls $zopim.livechat.window.hide()).

```
const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
const scriptNode=  document.createTextNode(zopim == null ? zopimJs : '$zopim.livechat.window.hide()');
scriptElement.async = true;
scriptElement.appendChild(scriptNode);
document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

How can I test this using Enzyme/Jest?
Ideally I want to test that that function hide() is called (rather than checking the results of that call).

Or maybe I need to approach the whole thing differently?

Any ideas welcome

cheers

Added: the zopim initialisation script is this:

```
window.$zopim||function(e,t){var i=$zopim=function(e){i._.push(e)},o=i.s=e.createElement(t),a=e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];i.set=function(e){i.set._.push(e)};i._=[];i.set._=[];o.async=!0;o.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");o.src="https://v2.zopim.com/?58crBwjpXFSYXv6eloiat27G1SqQOJvC";i.t=+new Date;o.type="text/javascript";a.parentNode.insertBefore(o,a)}(document,"script");$zopim(function(){var t="Customer Support";var i="Customer Support";var o="Please enter your message below. An expert will get back to you shortly.";$zopim.livechat.setOnConnected(function(){var e=$zopim.livechat.departments.getDepartment(t);if(typeof e=="undefined"){$zopim.livechat.setStatus("offline");$zopim.livechat.hideAll();return false}if(e.status=="offline"){$zopim.livechat.setStatus("offline");$zopim.livechat.hideAll()}else{$zopim.livechat.window.setTitle(i);$zopim.livechat.theme.setColor("#FF6B00");$zopim.livechat.theme.reload();$zopim.livechat.addTags(t);$zopim.livechat.departments.filter("");$zopim.livechat.prechatForm.setGreetings(o);$zopim.livechat.departments.setVisitorDepartment(t);$zopim.livechat.window.hide()}})});
```

so how would I mock this in the test? And the fact that that script runs asynchronously - how best to check it after mounting the component?

Answer (score 1):

you could add a class method that calls `$zopim.livechat.window.hide()` and use a watcher to check to see if that class method is called.

Based on your example code its hard to know how much deeper the testing can go without knowing how much `zopim` functionality you have mocked in your testing suite.

Comment: I haven't mocked any $zopim functionality. Maybe that is what I need to do. I'm still getting to grips with mocks so wasn't quite sure how to do it.
I think that might be the ideal solution.

Comment: I have added extra detail in the main question - thanks